# What does this code do for the picture class

Tags: java, image

```
public void modifyPicture()
{
Pixel pixel=null; 
Pixel[ ] pixels=this.getPixels();  
for(int x=0; x<this.getPixels().length/2; x++ ) 
{
 pixel= pixels [x];
 int r =pixel.getRed()/2
 int g=pixel.getGreen()/2; 
int b=pixel.getBlue()/2; 
pixel.setColor(new Color(r,g,b) ) )
  }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's iterating over every pixel in the image and dividing the value of each color channel by 2. The end result seems to be that it would darken the image hald the distance to black.

Comment: Not every pixel, only half of the pixels :-)

Comment: Indeed! The top half of the image!

Answer (score 0):

Every second pixel is divided by 2. This could be used f.e. to darken the whole pic.